# Shelosha Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three words of the Aseres Hadibros "Onochi Hashem Elokecha" = 173

Answer (score 2):

According to Rokeach (excerpt [here](http://www.responsa.co.il/searchg/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%20%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%97%20%5B%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%97%5D%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3%20%D7%A8%22%D7%97%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C_i_.aspx)), the fourth blessing of Musaf on (weekday) Rosh Chodesh contains 173 words. (Though by my count, Nusach Ashkenaz has 174, not counting [ולכפרת פשע which is recited sometimes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/saying-ulichaporas-pasha-in-musaf-of-rosh-chodesh), and Nusach Sefard has even more.)

Answer (score 1):

Avraham Avinu was 173 years old when Yaakov and Eisav turned 13.

Answer (score 1):

173 rabbis, headed by the *Aruch Laner*, protested the [Brunswick conference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbinical_Conference_of_Brunswick). Source: [*The Jewish Encyclopedia*](http://books.google.com/books?id=484oQCN_xecC&pg=PA264&dq=brunswick).