# Why is the atonement for פשע limited to leap years in the Amida for Musaf Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month, sin, musaf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Saying Ulichaporas Pasha in Musaf of Rosh Chodesh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/saying-ulichaporas-pasha-in-musaf-of-rosh-chodesh)

This question is a slightly different take on [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/saying-ulichaporas-pasha-in-musaf-of-rosh-chodesh). I have posted a comment there and await to see if it needs to be removed from here.

There are three expressions for different types of sin which we use widely, פשע and חטא, עון . Sometimes חטא is used as a generic form but otherwise all three occur together. Except, that is, in the [musaf of Rosh Chodesh](http://www.mysiddur.com/showSiddur.php?layout=2S&chapter=Rosh%20Chodesh&page=4) where פשע is only mentioned in a leap year.

It is inconceivable that this form of sin can only be atoned during this restricted period, so why is it left out during normal years?

With פשע, there are now thirteen expressions in this part of the Amida. But this is surely no justification for leaving it out!

Comment: Any possible answer here belongs there AFAICT... seems like this should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @msh210 An answer has been accepted there. It says because "pasha" is the most severe sin, it's reasonable that we only ask for forgiveness for it every few years. My question ("It is inconceivable ...") rejects this answer. The other answers do not touch on this point. That's why I posted it as a new question with a doubt about whether this is appropriate.

Comment: If you don't like the answers given there (and I'm with you on that, incidentally), then [try to solicit more](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty). I'm closing this as a duplicate.