# Ulchaparat pasha in Chazarat haShatz

Tags: halacha, calendar, shemoneh-esrei, rosh-chodesh-new-month, amen

When "ulchaparat pasha" is said in the Chazarat haShatz of Rosh Chodesh, how should the amein of the tzibbur be handled? Should the amein from "velislichat avon" be deferred until after "pasha," or should an additional amein added? Why or why not?

Comment: Is this a [tag:minhag] question (please record how this is handled by various communities) or a [tag:halacha] question (what reasons are there to insert or remove an amen)?

Comment: Good question; at this point it's a halacha question, given that I don't (yet) know which governs this issue

Comment: related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/saying-ulichaporas-pasha-in-musaf-of-rosh-chodesh/3296#3296

Comment: See the Vilna siddur which brings the practices of the Gra,it seems that it is part of vslichos avon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Luach Davar B'Ito 5771 page 283](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51553&st=&pgnum=283&hilite=) says that you do not say Amein after V'leslichas Avon, you say Amein after V'lchaporas Pesha.

Comment: Why? Who publishes this calendar? What qualifications does he have? To what communty/ies are his rulings aimed?

Comment: @DoubleAA: It is published by R' Mordechai Genut. [He has many Haskamos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51553&st=&pgnum=12&hilite=) from all types of Rabanim.